# Not getting proper output while deleting the records

Tags: mysql

I have 2 tables named student and teacher. I am using following query to get the output i.e

```
DELETE from student, teacher 
USING student, teacher 
WHERE teacher.teacher_id = student.teacher_id 
AND teacher.teacher_id !=99
```

Problem is that when I run that query I get some other row in teacher table whose teacher_id is !=99 Actually in my student table some student not belong to any of the teacher.

Please help me out

Comment: Firstly What exactly do you want, **`1.Select 2.Delete`** ? If **`Delete`** than what all records should be deleted and what should be **`condition`**?

Comment: Not sure what you mean. Are you saying that the problem is after the query is executed, there are still records in the tables where `teacher_id` is not equal to 99? Is this only in the `student` table or both? Do all the remaining records have a `teacher_id` of `null`?

Comment: Another question is why complicate your query? I think it will execute faster and be easier to understand to do 2 queries seperated by `;`. This would be `DELETE FROM student WHERE teacher_id <> 99 OR teacher_id IS NULL; DELETE FROM teacher WHERE teacher_id <> 99 OR teacher_id IS NULL`

Answer (score 1):

You stated in your question that:

*Problem is that when I run that query I get some other row in teacher table whose* `teacher_id is !=99`

But in your query, you have the where condition:

```
teacher.teacher_id !=99
```

So I guess you want to delete `STUDENTS` who belong to `TEACHER 99`.

This should work:

```
DELETE FROM students
WHERE teacher_id = 99;
```

Or if I'm wrong and you want to delete all `STUDENTS` who do not belong to `TEACHER 99`, then:

```
DELETE FROM students
WHERE teacher_id <> 99;
```